# Mysql query doesn't fetch the rows for PRIMARY column

Tags: mysql, innodb

When I use a select query on the primary field it doesn't fetch the data, if I use BETWEEN query the data is fetched. Does anyone know what reason it could be?

```
select * from addresses where id = 76;
```

The above query doesn't fetch the data. Whereas in, if I use BETWEEN query it fetches the data.

```
select * from addresses where id BETWEEN 76 and 80;
```

This issue is happening for particular rows in sequence but not for all the rows.

Do I need to recreate the index for ID?

Comment: How is `id` defined?

Comment: It is an integer with auto increment and unique. @PM77-1

Comment: Try repairing the index.

Comment: what happens if you change WHERE to WHERE id > 76 AND id < 80

Comment: Does the record with id=76 exists?

Comment: Yes, it does exist. When fetched with BETWEEN or less than or greater than it provides results. @Wiimm

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for repairing the index? @Barmar

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html

Comment: That `BETWEEN`returns a result is not an evidence that record id=76 exists. What is the result for `select id from addresses where id BETWEEN 76 and 80;`

Comment: @Wiimm It results in showing all the data for 76 till 80

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If you are using MyISAM, rebuild the indexes.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`